# Can I be able to change font-family using bootstrap 3 alone, without using any CSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to change the font-family of a caption in my program using bootstrap 3. Is that possible without using CSS code?

Comment: Bootstrap is, just CSS and Javascript. To specify a font family for an element you need to use CSS or Javascrp.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the source code of bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/
But that would be an overkill.

The simplest way to change font family is **CSS**.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kenan Balija. So it means that we don't have a class defining font family in bootstrap framework.. Is that what you mean?